# How to add another password into iOS Keychain?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, passwords, keychain

I am trying to use the KeychainWrapper class provided in this Apple sample code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain

My plan is to create username and password for Login screen and also a passcode/pin for Passcode screen in my app. So my question is how to add another passcode into Keychain since I noticed that in GenericKeychain sample there are listed only username and password. In the end, I would like to have a username, password and passcode in Keychain within my app.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if that can be done.... at max you can create two username with the second userame havinge "_passcode" attached to it and save the passcode to it...

for eg:

```
username: ankit
password: 1234
```

save this to keychain

and then again save another pair using

```
username: ankit_passcode
passcode: 4321
```

you can then retrieve it using the username provided...

hoping this helps.

Comment: This answer will work. Use consistent keys when using `- (void)setObject:(id)inObject forKey:(id)key;` and it should be straight forward

Comment: Got it! I never thought about how to add another generic password item to the keychain. Now it is working so well. Thank you so much!